# Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined in Rails AJAX error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to implement error messages with my AJAX registration form but code below returns an error when I type wrong password and nothing shows up:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var form = $('.centralized-login')
  form.submit( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var email = $('#email-input').val()
    var password = $('#password-input').val()
    var req = $.ajax('/user_role', {
    data: {
      email
    }
    })

    req.then( function(result) {
      var { role } = result
      switch (role) {
        case 'company_manager':
          $.ajax('/users/sign_in', {
            method: "POST",
            data: {
              "user[email]": email ,
              "user[password]": password,
              "authenticity_token": $('input[name="authenticity_token"]').val()
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, req){
              window.location="/users/sign_in"
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              id.find(password).html("");
              console.log(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
            }
            })
```

Should I provide some `id` of this input?

Here is my view:

```
<!-- email -->
<div class="vr-field row">
  <div class="vr-field__desc col-sm-3 col-md-offset-1 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <%= t 'users.passwords.new.email' %>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="vr-textfield-wrapper">
      <%= f.email_field :email, id: "email-input", class: "vr-textfield", placeholder: t('users.passwords.new.email_placeholder'), required: true, aria_required: true, autofocus: true %>
      <span class="vr-field__invalid-msg"><%= t 'users.passwords.new.valid_email'%></span>

      <% if resource.errors.full_messages_for(:email).first %>
        <div class="vr-textfield-wrapper">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <div class ="error-explanation">
              <%= t('activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.email.not_found_in_database') %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Well where exactly is `id` declared?

Comment: Do you really want the line `id.find(password).html("");` in the error of the AJAX call?  Wouldn't an error mean that no `id` would get returned even if you tried to declare it?  Obviously, you would need to declare it first to get any of this to work, but what gets returned in the error that you could get an `id` from?

Comment: @Pointy I think it's in the View container being passed in from "email-input", if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @zfrisch If it's not declared somewhere in the lexical scope of that reference, it doesn't matter if it's in some random container object.

Comment: @Pointy so how should I declared it? should I use `<span>` in the view? I thought it would be enough if I do something like `var password = $('#password-input').val()`

Comment: I don't understand that at all; what does `password` have to do with the `id` symbol that's causing the error?

Comment: @Pointy ok so if I change it to `id.find('selector').html("");` should I declare this `selector` somewhere? because if I change it I still get this error - `Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined`

Comment: look if `id` is not defined anywhere you're still going to get the error. What do you expect `id` to mean?

Comment: @Pointy I thought `id` means `id` of the field where errors should be displayed

Comment: A reference to a symbol like `id` in JavaScript has to be a reference to a **declared** symbol. They don't just float into existence from nowhere.

Comment: @Pointy ok I'm totally confused here, where should I declared this symbol? in `JS` file? in the View? in the controller? If I delete this line it's just simple show me `error Unauthorized` in console